# Div width("%s") alignment with firefox

Tags: html

When I divide page into columns using  tags by passing width values in percentages, that is I declare the body's div width as 100% inside which two div's are declared as 20% & 80% width, it's working fine in IE8, but not in firefox unless I change the second width from 80% to 79%. Can u pls explain why?

Comment: You will get faster (and less guessed) answers when you post a reduced example with which people can reproduce what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. define a proper doctype: `<!doctype html>` **This is very important for IE, because he  uses another boxmodell if you don't!**
2. be aware, that the current w3c-boxmodell only takes the content-width into account. This means, if you have margin, border and/or padding declared, this messes up your width.

If you define 80%/20% columns, but they have `border:1px ...` this will mess up your design because effectively this means 80+20 = 100% + 4px for the border -> your page will break.

You can switch boxmodell in newer browsers [( called box-sizing: from IE8 on)](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) to use a "better" boxmodell, which accounts padding and/or border into your width declarations.

edit:

[MDN-Link regarding box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing)

Comment: @Honey glad i could help. You should accept the answer (click the green checkmark)  to indicate to other users, that your problem has been solved.